# Find $\operatorname{Gal}(K_2/Q)$ from $\operatorname{Gal}(K_1K_2/K_1)$ and $\operatorname{Gal}(K_1/Q)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I have some field $Q$ (it is in fact $\mathbb{Q}_p$ but I don't think that it is important here), with two extensions $K_1$ and $K_2$. The field $K_2=Q(\alpha_i)_i$ is the splitting field of some polynomial $H\in Q[X]$ and $K_1=Q(\xi)$ is the rupture field of some polynomial $X^l-p$. We assume that we know the groups $\operatorname{Gal}(K_1K_2/K_1)$ (it is a cyclic group) and $\operatorname{Gal}(K_1/Q)$ (Galois group of the rupture field of $X^l-p$).

Question: is there some easy way to get $\operatorname{Gal}(K_2/Q)$? with some additionaly hypothesis if needed?

In good circumstancies we have $\operatorname{Gal}(K_1K_2/Q)=\operatorname{Gal}(K_1/Q)\times\operatorname{Gal}(K_2/Q)$ and $\operatorname{Gal}(K_1K_2/Q)/\operatorname{Gal}(K_1K_2/K_2)=\operatorname{Gal}(K_2/Q)$ but I don't see how to combine that to get $\operatorname{Gal}(K_2/Q)$.

Comment: Essentially, you know that a group $G$ is given as $G=MN$ with $N$ normal, and you also know the structure of $N$ and of $G/N$; and you are trying to figure out what the structure of $M$ is. This is not a fully determined thing; even knowing the structure of $G$ from $N$ and $G/N$ is not necessarily completely determined. You are going to need some (a lot?) of extra information to bring to bear, though some of it may be clear from knowing things about your fields. But you apparently know *exactly* who $K_1$ is, so why do you need $K_2$ at all?

Comment: I made a mistake: it is $Gal(K_1/Q)$ that is known and $Gal(K_2/Q)$ that I search: $Gal(K_2/Q)$ is not so easy because it is a decomposition group (and not a rupture groupe as $Gal(K_1/Q)$ is).

Comment: To answer precisely your question: I need $K_1$ because $Gal(K_1K_2/K_1)=Gal(Q(\xi\alpha_i)/Q(\xi))_i$ is the decomposition groupe of $H(\xi X)$ which I can find by Krasner lemma.

Comment: I forgot to precise that $Gal(K_1K_2/K_1)$ is a cyclic group!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Arturo Magidin in the comments, knowing $N$ and $G/N$ are not enough to determine $G$ up to isomorphism, even in the simplest case where $N$ and or $G/N$ is cyclic.

Think about the case where $G$ has order $4$ and $N$ has order $2$. Both groups $N$ and $G/N$ are cyclic of order $2$, whatever $G$ is. From this information, you cannot decide whether $G$ is cyclic or isomorphic to the Klein group.

Unless you have precise information on $H$ or $K_2$, it is impossible to  give a satisfactory answer to your question.

Comment: I think you're right: it's not a purely galois theory problem. I'll try to compute it with comuter algebric system but Sagemath doesn't do that on $\mathbb{Q}_p$...